# Flyway with Jenkins - Unable to resolve location

Tags: jenkins, flyway

I am trying to integrate db migrations with `Flyway` in the ci/cd pipeline by running a shell command in one of the stages. (since I am not allowed to add any new plugins to the pipeline, so can't use the Flyway plugin)

I have tried it like:

```
    stage('migrate-sql') {
      steps {
        sh """
          docker run --rm \
          -v /GetShorty/Apis/Sql:/flyway/sql \
          boxfuse/flyway:5.2.4 \
          -url=jdbc:postgresql://****:5432/**** \
          -user=**** \
          -password=**** \
          -baselineOnMigrate=false \
          -locations=/GetShorty/Apis/Sql \
          -connectRetries=60 \
          migrate
        """
      }
    }
```

but no migrations are applied since it doesn't seem to find the migrations folder

```
WARNING: Unable to resolve location /GetShorty/Apis/Sql

Successfully validated 0 migrations (execution time 00:00.378s)

Current version of schema "public": << Empty Schema >>

Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

Considering the following projecture structure:

[image: project structure]

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbling on this [issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mesos-plugin/issues/159) I realized I was facing a similar problem.

The way I managed to solve it was to create a seperate folder in the root project called `flyway` that contains a `sql` folder with all the migrations and the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM boxfuse/flyway:5.2.4

COPY ./sql ./sql
```

Going back to the `jenkins` file I added a new step to build the docker image:

```
  DOCKER_IMAGE_FLYWAY = "flyway"

  stages {
    stage('build docker images') {
      steps {
        script {
          dockerImage_flyway = docker.build("$DOCKER_REGISTRY/${DOCKER_PROJECT}/${DOCKER_IMAGE_FLYWAY}:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", "flyway")
        }
      }
    }
```

and modified the migrations stage to use the that image

```
stage('migrate-sql') {
      steps {
        sh """
            docker run --rm \
            "$DOCKER_REGISTRY/${DOCKER_PROJECT}/${DOCKER_IMAGE_FLYWAY}:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}" \
            -url=jdbc:postgresql://****:5432/**** \
            -user=**** \
            -password=**** \
            -baselineOnMigrate=false \
            -schemas=**** \
            -connectRetries=60 \
            migrate
          """
      }
    }
```

Now works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

The docker volume settings is mounting the `/GetShorty/Apis/Sql` directory on the host to the `/flyway/sql` directory inside the container:

```
-v /GetShorty/Apis/Sql:/flyway/sql
```

Flyway is running inside the container so the locations flag needs to be the directory inside:

```
-locations=/flyway/sql
```

Comment: I realized this issue throughout the day and already made the changes. What is weird is that if I run the docker command locally it applies the migrations, but if it is run thourgh jenkins it doesn't